# How can I make Django choose a specific default database when it starts up with command line argument

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

I want Django to use a specific database(`sqlite`) as default by an argument given when It starts up regardless of `settings.py.`

For this purpose, I added below code in `manage.py` so that `settings.DATABASES` can be set with the argument when it starts up.

```
# manage.py

from myapp import settings
settings.DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(settings.DB_PATH, sys.argv[3]),
    },
}
```

But It doesn't work....Django still accesses origin database represented in `settings.py`

I think it is because Django already has done with setting default DB before I change settings.DATABASES in `manage.py`.

As a result, the change doesn't have any effect.

When does Django choose default database with settings?
If I can change settings.DATABASES before Django choose default database, I will work i think.

Is there any way to change default database at runtime?
So that even Django choose already default database I can change it.

It doesn't mean to change database dynamically using `model.objects.using('dbname').

Comment: Why on earth would you do such a thing ? What's the **real** problem you're trying to solve ?

Answer (score 1):

```
./manage.py migrate --database=default
```